# How to resolve Connection timed out exception when using Jsch through Jump server?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am trying to connect to a server through a jump server. I am using Jsch 0.51 and trying to connect using the `setPortForwardingL` method.

However, I am getting the following exception while connecting:
`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out`

I am basically following the example given here: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html

What could be the reasons for this exception?

**Edit**: Adding the code snippet which is throwing the exception:

```
//Trying to connect to the Jump server in this snippet
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect(); //Getting the ConnectException here
```

Comment: Where in the sequence do you get the connection timeout? It would be helpful to see the code.

Comment: Hi @Petter, I have added the code snippet where exception is occurring.

Comment: Does it work to ssh to the same hostname and port using the command line?

Comment: Yes, this was run from a Windows machine, and I am able to connect to the server via putty from the same machine.